# How to Filter excel Range that contain letter M

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, office-automation

How to apply filter to the excel `Range` that contain letter "M" for example.

I tried the below but not filtering data the contain letter M.

`sheet2.UsedRange.AutoFilter(1, "M", EXCEL.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues);`

Comment: AND with nothing gives nothing.  Try values : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlautofilteroperator?view=excel-pia

Comment: @jdweng I read that but couldn't do the filter I need

Comment: Some examples are using a string for the first param, re: `AutoFilter("1", ...` Have you tried using a string?